# Calling a Powershell script from a PS1 script in the context of a Github workflow fails

Tags: azure, powershell, github-actions

I have a multi-stage (job) pipeline in Github and in one of those stages, I call a `.ps1` script.  The script seems to be found.  But when that script tries to call another `.ps1` script (that is located in the same folder), I get an exception that the script or cmdlet is not found.

I believe it has something to do with the 'context directory' of the script not being set to the actual script directory, though I am not sure. When executing the script locally, everything works perfectly.

These are the relevant parts of code:

#### Github workflow

In this section, we are saving the relevant files as artifact for the later stage (see next snippet)

```yaml
create-pipeline-artifacts:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Upload bicep files as pipeline artifact  
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: bicep
        path: deployment/bicep
    - name: Upload powershell scripts as pipeline artifact  
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: powershell
        path: deployment/powershell
    - name: Upload integrations as pipeline artifact  
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: integrations
        path: integrations
```

In the following section, I am actually retrieving those files and persisting them in the `.artifacts` folder.  After which, I actually try to execute the script itself.

```yaml
Deploy-Integrations:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  if: always()
  environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
  steps:
  - name: Azure Login
    uses: azure/login@v1
    with:
      creds: '${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}'
      enable-AzPSSession: true
  - name: Download powershell files from pipeline artifact
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: powershell
      path: ./artifacts/powershell
  - name: Download integration files
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: integrations
      path: ./artifacts/integrations
    - name: Deploy integrations
      uses: azure/powershell@v1
      with:
        inlineScript: ./artifacts/powershell/deploy-logicapp-folder.ps1 -environmentAcronym ${{ inputs.environmentAcronym }} -location ${{ inputs.region }} -rootFolder './artifacts/integrations/'
        azPSVersion: "latest"
```

#### The two powershell files

`deploy-logicapp-folder.ps1`

```
param ($rootFolder, $location, $environmentAcronym)
$locationAcronym = 'weu'

Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Recurse -Filter *.definition.json |
    ForEach-Object {
        # This is where the exception occurs!
        & ./deploy-logicapp.ps1 -logicAppDefinitionFile $_.FullName -location $location -locationAcronym $locationAcronym -environmentAcronym $environmentAcronym
    }
```

`deploy-logicapp-folder.ps1`

```
param ($logicAppDefinitionFile, $location, $environmentAcronym, $locationAcronym)

### SET UP LOGIC APP NAME
$logicAppName = Split-Path $logicAppDefinitionFile -leaf
$logicAppName = $logicAppName.Replace('.definition.json', '')
$logicAppName = "$locationAcronym-$environmentAcronym-int-la-$logicAppName"

# Most code removed for brevity as irrelevant
```

#### The actual error message

```
Run ./artifacts/powershell/deploy-logicapp-folder.ps1 -environmentAcronym dev -location westeurope -rootFolder './artifacts/integrations/'
  
ForEach-Object: /home/runner/work/backend/backend/artifacts/powershell/deploy-logicapp-folder.ps1:21
Line |
  21 |      ForEach-Object ***
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term './deploy-logicapp.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a
     | cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling
     | of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
     | and try again.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

#### Edit history

- Updated to use `azure/powershell@v1` as step instead